# Checkbox list values are not binding on View GET Request in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ViewModel I have the following two lists (one is used for showing all available categories in the form and the other is used for just the user selected category values):

```
public List<CategoryViewModel> Categories{ get; set; }
public List<string> SelectedCategoryValues { get; set; }
```

In my View I have the following inside of one of my forms:

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories) {
     <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectedCategoryValues" 
          value="@category.Value">@category.Name</label>
     </div>
}
```

When submitting the form the model binder is correctly binding SelectedCategoryValues list.

However, when loading the page the selected checkboxes are not automatically selecting.

**The following code is in my Edit GET Action:**

```
    var vm = new ProductEditViewModel()
    {
        Id = product.Id,
        Name = product.Name,
        Categories = new List<CategoryViewModel>()
        {
            new CategoryViewModel() { Name = "Category 1", Value = "category1" },
            new CategoryViewModel() { Name = "Category 2", Value = "category2" },
            new CategoryViewModel() { Name = "Category 3", Value = "category3" }
        },
        SelectedCategoryValues = productCategories.Select(c => c.Value).ToList()
    };

    return View(vm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include something like `bool IsSelected{get;set;}` into `CategoryViewModel` and assign values in the controller.

```
var vm = new ProductEditViewModel()
{
    Id = product.Id,
    Name = product.Name,
    Categories = new List<CategoryViewModel>()
    {
        new CategoryViewModel() { Name = "Category 1", Value = "category1",
         IsSelected = productCategories.Where(c => c.Value == "category1").Count() > 0 ? true : false},
         //do the same
        //new CategoryViewModel() { Name = "Category 2", Value = "category2" },
        //new CategoryViewModel() { Name = "Category 3", Value = "category3" }
    },
    //not required
    //SelectedCategoryValues = productCategories.Select(c => c.Value).ToList()
};

return View(vm);
```

And in the view

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories) {
     <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" checked="@category.IsSelected" name="SelectedCategoryValues" 
          value="@category.Value">@category.Name</label>
     </div>
}
```